# SystemVerilog & RegEx: "\d" is not recognized as a character class

Tags: regex, system-verilog

I'm trying to use regular expressions in SystemVerilog. The character class "\d" (a digit) seems not to work, while other character classes like "\w", "\s"  work fine. I tried with SVLIB and UVM, same behavior.

To reproduce I wrote the code below. The code does nothing but test "1" against regex "\d" and "\w" using UVM and SVLIB.

```
module SandBox;

import svlib_pkg::*;
import uvm_pkg::*;

initial
begin

Str myString;
Regex regex;

string testString;
string reString;

testString = "1";
reString = "\\d";

myString = Str::create(testString);
regex = Regex::create();
regex.setRE(reString);

$display("-------------------------------------");
$display("test string: %s", testString);
$display("regex: %s", reString);

if (regex.test(myString)) begin

    $display("SVLIB Test passed!");

end

if (!uvm_re_match(reString, testString)) begin

    $display("UVM Test passed!");   

end

testString = "1";
reString = "\\w";

myString = Str::create(testString);
regex = Regex::create();
regex.setRE(reString);

$display("-------------------------------------");
$display("test string: %s", testString);
$display("regex: %s", reString);

if (regex.test(myString)) begin

    $display("SVLIB Test passed!");

end

if (!uvm_re_match(reString, testString)) begin

    $display("UVM Test passed!");   

end

end

endmodule
```

I have the following output:

```
-------------------------------------
test string: 1
regex: \d
-------------------------------------
test string: 1
regex: \w
SVLIB Test passed!
UVM Test passed!
```

What is the reason for this behavior? The underlying system? Something in SV syntax?

Comment: [0-9]+ instead?

Comment: `\d` is just a conventional symbol, it is not mandatory for a software to recognise it. Just use `[0-9]`

Comment: Is it the same on your systems or is it just mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the **svlib User Guide and Programmer's Reference**:

> svlib uses the "extended
>   regular expression" dialect of the C library's POSIX-compliant regular expression subsystem,
>   and you can find full details of how to write regular expressions in this dialect by consulting
>   the man-page man 7 regex or any of the numerous online regular expression tutorials. The
>   regex dialect of svlib is in almost all respects the same as that used by the Unix/Linux
>   command egrep.

The POSIX regular expressions standard (man 7 regexp), in turn, defines the available character classes as follows:

> Within a bracket expression, the name of a character class enclosed in "[:" and ":]" stands for the list of all characters belonging to that class.  Standard character class names are:
>
> ```
> alnum   digit   punct
> alpha   graph   space
> blank   lower   upper
> cntrl   print   xdigit
> ```

So, the digits characters class has to be specified as:

```
[[:digit:]]
```

using the canonical syntax.

The `\d`, `\w` or `\s` are a so called [Shorthand Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html), which are not defined by the POSIX standard, so their availability depends on the Regexp 
engine implementation you are using.

Some regexp engines choose to implement all of them, others (e.g. `sed` or `grep`, only implement a subset, not including `\d`.

The `svlib` implementation is claimed to be `egrep` compatible, and `egrep` does not support `\d`.